# Efficient way of finding a subset in R

Tags: python, r

I'm working on a financial dataset. The dataset has 3M rows corresponding to 30k companies and contains numeric, float, categorical, strings etc.

My algorithm requires performing computation on all the rows of a given company. For that I use the `subset` function to identify the relevant rows.

But as you can imagine this is highly inefficient because in order to identify the subset, R has to traverse through all the 3M rows. If I repeat this step for all 30k companies, R will traverse through the dataset 30k times, which is horrible.

A better way for doing this would be to somehow group the dataset by companies and being able to access just the required rows.

I know I can do this very efficiently in `Python` using dictionaries where the `keys` would correspond to the `name of company` and values will be a `list` of `all the rows` for that company, thereby allowing me to access the relevant rows in one shot.

But I am not sure how to do a similar efficient storage/retrieval in R. Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: For large financial data sets, I use `data.table` with `setkey` or `setkeyv`. The benchmarks show that this is the fastest way to do calculations. Faster than `dplyr` or pandas in python: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-:-Grouping

Comment: Also, with data.table, you can do the calculation on all companies at once using `by=company`

Comment: I hate "drive-by down-voting" too; in my opinion it's a not helpful feature of the mostly excellent StackOverflow system. My guess about the downvotes is that they're looking for a sample data set, like I provided in my first two lines, or more details on exactly what kind of computations you want to do on each company. You say you don't need code, but it would be a better question if you showed what you were currently doing with `subset` as applied to some generic data set.

Comment: your edit should be a comment, not an edit to the body of the question ...

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 2):

P Lapointe's comment about `data.table` is spot-on, I don't think you'll find anything better. For comparison, the best base R way that I know is to make a key by splitting the row indices and then subsetting on that. That's vastly faster than either using subset individually or splitting the entire data frame. `plyr` is about the same speed as splitting the row indices. `data.table` is orders of magnitude faster. Timings are on my system from a single run, I didn't bother to benchmark properly.

```
d <- data.frame(company=factor(rep(1:3e4,100)),
                other=round(sample(runif(3e6)),2))

## using subset individually
## 1.8 sec for 10 companies, so ~540 sec total
out0 <- sapply(levels(d$company)[1:10], function(companyi) {
    di <- subset(d, company==companyi)
    mean(di$other)
})

## ## "standard" way; split the data frame and 
## ## the split is prohibitively slow, probably too memory intensive
## ds <- split(d, d$company)
## sapply(ds, function(di) mean(di$other))

## not too bad, but still slow, possibly the best base R method?
## 2.6 sec to do only first 1000 companies, so ~78 sec total
idx <- split(seq_len(nrow(d)), d$company)
out1 <- sapply(idx[1:1000], function(i) mean(d[i,]$other))

## plyr, about the same timing as above
library(plyr)
out2 <- ddply(d[1:1e4,], ~company, summarize, m=mean(other))

## data table is the clear speed demon
## 0.07 sec to do all companies
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(d)
out3 <- DT[, mean(other), keyby=company]
```

Comment: 100% agree that a package with grouping support is the best way to go. I'd add is that it's difficult from the question to get at is what types of algorithms are being used, which could impact whether something like `plyr` + `mcmapply` would be useful (e.g. there's a complex algorithm that you could parallelize operations by splitting after doing as much grouping as possible).

Comment: At this stage, here are some example I am looking to perform on the rows for each company: 1) `Data Cleaning` which involves multiple heuristics like identifying rows with missing data, filtering rows from a particular category, filtering rows with values less than / more than some cutoff, removing rows with returns missing from the initial (or final) couple of rows, identifying months which are missing, etc. 2)  Mostly applying different regression techniques on this clean data.

Comment: @Aaron: Thank you for your answer.